# How can I run QGIS Flowmapper in batch mode?

Tags: qgis, flow-map

I installed and used the Flowmapper plugin in QGIS. It works perfect. However, I have numerous matrices that I need to create desire lines. Doing it one by one is pretty tedious so I wanted to run them in batch. For this, I tried writing a python function which calls the function

```
shapefilemaker(typeofcalculation,CreateShpNodes,IncludeNodeNames,fulldirectorystring,outputfilename,outputfilenamenodes,fulldirODinput,fulldirPTinput,fulldirPTNamesinput,combotext)
```

inside `flowpyv07.py` However since it lacks proper documentation, I'm having some difficulty using it. Has anyone tried this?